# Python: After creating random numbers, how do I associate those numbers with the list i've made

Tags: python, loops, random, for-loop

So basically I needed to create a list of buffers labeled [0,1,2,3,4,5,10,25,100]. Then I needed to create random numbers between (0.75 and 4.75)+3. Now I need to Print something like "Buffer 3 took and average of **x** seconds." The **x** would be the random number generated. Each buffer must have its own  random number

```
def main():
    buffer= [0,1,2,3,4,5,10,25,100]
    time= random.uniform(0.75,4.75)+3
    sum=0
    for i in range (1, 500):
        sum = sum + time;
        average= sum/1500
        for buffer in range(0,1,2,3,4,5,10,25,100):
           print("For Buffer",buffer,",the average time is",average,".")
```

---

[SOLVED]

```
#Lab 1 using python.
Import random  #Importing random number generator.
def main():
    buffers= [0,1,2,3,4,5,10,25,100]; #Defining the buffers using list.
    for buffer in buffers:
        sum=0;

        for i in range (1, 500): # Create a loop which will create random number and increment 500 times.
            time= (random.uniform (0.75,4.75))+3
            sum = sum + time

        average= sum/500; #Finding the average of each buffers random numbers.

        print("For Buffer",buffer,",the average time is",average,"."); #Print the output.
```

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on what you're asking here, but if you want a different random number for each buffer, you need to either move the random number generation *inside* your buffer for-loop, or you need to store all your random numbers somewhere (e.g. a list) as you generate them and then iterate over that in your buffer for-loop.

Comment: Why not `random.uniform(3.75, 7.75)`?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change it so your average calculation is done in your for loop.

```
buffer= [0,1,2,3,4,5,10,25,100]
    for buffer in range(0,1,2,3,4,5,10,25,100):
          sum=0
          for i in range (1, 500):
             time= random.uniform(0.75,4.75)+3
             sum = sum + time;
             average= sum/1500
          print("For Buffer",buffer,",the average time is",average,".")
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be in the inner for loop? Now the sum will just be `time*500`, and `average==time/3`, which makes little sense.

Comment: Good point, I didn't actually look at the calculations, and just moved the code into the other loop. Will edit to reflect this

Comment: I also suspect that either 500 or 1500 is a mistake on @Dizzy's part.

Answer (score 0):

You could associate each buffer with its average value using a dictionary using the buffer dirrectly as a key and for the value its average value.

```
def main():
    buffer= [0,1,2,3,4,5,10,25,100]
    time= random.uniform(0.75,4.75)+3
    sum=0
    dict_of_buffers = {}
    for i in range (1, 500):
        sum = sum + time;
        average= sum/1500
        for buffer in range(0,1,2,3,4,5,10,25,100):
            print("For Buffer",buffer,",the average time is",average,".")
            dict_of_buffers[buffer] = average
```